# Java initialising classes with populators in their constructor

Tags: java, performance, oop, reflection, constructor

I have a repository of classes in a package, in their constructor, they populate a component of the server.

For example:

The master class:

```
public abstract class MessageDecoder<T> {

    public MessageDecoder(boolean logicType, Integer...opcodes) {
        for (int opcode : opcodes) {
            GameConstants.RELEASE.register(logicType, opcode, this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the encoded message to send to the client.
     * 
     * @param the {@link GamePacket} ready to be read.
     * @return a constructed message ready to be handled.
     */
    public abstract T decode(GamePacket packet);

}
```

And the repoistory classes look like:

```
public final class PlayerWalkPathMessageDecoder extends MessageDecoder<PlayerWalkPathMessage> {

    public PlayerWalkPathMessageDecoder() {
        super(true, 8, 58);
    }

    @Override 
    public PlayerWalkPathMessage decode(GamePacket packet) {

        return null;
    }

}
```

In the master class you can see how the method

```
register(logicType, opcode, this);
```

is being used to register the class to a

```
map < Integer, MessageDecoder< ? > >
```

But during runtime, the map will not be populated because the repository classes have not been constructed yet.

This warrents me using an empty iterator to get the classes to be constructed:

```
Iterate.classes("bin/com/web/net/decoders", clazz -> {


});
```

Is there a better way to construct the classes located in a repository package?

Comment: note: `super(true, 8, 58);` use some constants ;) and why not int[]? or some object to warp this?

Comment: also what is `Iterate.classes`? this is some your method? or some library? Otherwise if your question is just about looking for better way - I would say it is fine, but I would scan for annotation using some library like Reflections or ClassGraph

Answer (score 0):

You have that register call in constructor, but you never create instance of that class? But I think that you just skipped some code or it is other small mistake so:

I think it is fine, but they are 3 other solutions I can think about:

1. Just init them manually.
2. Create some annotation to mark packet classes, you can even use them to store some basic data like that opcodes as they seems to be constant for each class?
   And then use some library like ClassGraph or Reflections to get all classes with that annotation to load them and create instance of them.
3. Use annotation processors to generate class that will init them "manually" and call only that single class. Then you have everything at compile time.